# How to get list of all music in specific directory and all subdirectories using MediaStore

Tags: java, android, mediastore

What I need is to get result like from this code

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
```

but in a specific directory, not from all directories.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = null;
    try {
        musicCursor = musicResolver.query(uri,
                new String[]{
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                },
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[]{new File("some path to directory").getCanonicalPath()},
                null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this method `moveToFirst()`
 returns false so as I understood it's empty.
Thanks for your future help.

Comment: You are asking Media.DATA to be equal to "some path...." but the MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA holds the full path including the track and its extension so the condition will never be true. What you should do is use the LIKE operator. Enclose your path as follows

        searchpath = "%" + strpath + "%";// looking for path string

and MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "LIKE? ". The query will now look for your path string contained within the fully qualified path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   searchpath = "%" + yourpath + "%";// looking for path string
   ContentResolver musicResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
  Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
  Cursor musicCursor = null;
  try {
    musicCursor = musicResolver.query(uri,
            new String[]{
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            },
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "LIKE? ",
            new String[]{searchpath},
            null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```